# What easy alcohol drinks can I possibly brew while camping for several days at a time?

Tags: history, brewing, drink, tradition

**What easy alcohol drinks can I possibly brew while on camping for an extended time?**

Do any of you out there now of some traditional drinks that we can try brewing while camping in the great outdoors?

I would prefer a traditional and recognized drink like [***tiswin***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiswin), along with the basic recipes to go along with it.

I am not interested in a high alcohol content, but rather a simple and traditional to brew along with it's recipe! Historical drink would be awesome.

Comment: By "brew" do you mean "mix" as in the answer?  If you really mean ferment, perhaps Homebrew.SE would be a better place to get answers.

Comment: [Mmmmm…mulled wine. ♡](https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/mulled-wine-recipe/)

Answer (score 1):

### Grog? yohoho

---

Boil water in a large saucepan. Add sugar, mint leaves and spices. Bring to an acceptable level, reduce heat and simmer for about 15 minutes. Remove from heat, strain, add rum and stir well. Cover with a lid and let steep for another 15 minutes. The drink should be served immediately.

---

- Water (clean) 500ml.
- Rum (dark) 0.75ml.
- Sugar 2 tablespoons
- Carnation 21 pcs.
- Ground black pepper 0.5 teaspoon
- Cinnamon 0.5 teaspoon
- Mint 1 pc.

### Carnation(Cloves)

[image]

[Cloves (spice)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clove)

Comment: What is "Carnation"? All I can think of is the flowers or the can of evaporated milk, and neither normally comes in "pcs.".

Comment: Cloves are optional, but i added photo and wiki